# imbalanced classification using undersampling and oversampling using pytorch python

Tags: python, pytorch, imbalanced-data, smote

I want to use oversampling and under sampling techniques together
I have 6 classes with number of samples as following:
class 0 250000
class 1 48000
class 2 40000
class 3 38000
class 4 35000
class 5 7000
I want to use smot to make all classes balance and equal same size
class 0 40000
class 1 40000
class 2 40000
class 3 40000
class 4 40000
class 5 40000
I know how to make oversampling or undersampling for all data but how use them together with multi class classification

Comment: Did you check SMOTE implementation by ‘imbalanced-learn’? [Docs](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) for the model

Comment: i checked it ,it works on oversampling the minority classes but i want to undersample some classes and oversample some classes

Comment: Choose data points randomly for the class that you want to under-sample. Or you might choose the most distinct samples (by some metric, say euclidean distance), probably q better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I Try this

```
ros = RandomUnderSampler()
X, y=ros.fit_resample(mydata, labels)
strategy = {0:40000, 1:40000, 2:40000, 3:40000, 4:40000, 5:40000}
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=strategy)
X, y=over.fit_resample(X, y)
```